# How to check if flink yarn session is already running?

Tags: apache-flink

How to check if flink yarn session is already running in a flink cluster?

In particular I want to check this programmatically and start a session if it is not running as part of automated deployment.

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/cli.html doesn't seem to have any obvious commands.

Answer (score 2):

If it's already running, Flink's REST API will be listening on some port. You could use something like `curl server:8081` to see if it's available. If it's not running, curl will exit with a status of 7 to indicate that the connection was refused.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this:

```
/usr/bin/yarn application -list 2>/dev/null | grep -i "Flink session" | awk '{print $1}'`
```